# update Object value globally

Tags: javascript, object, mutation, spread-syntax

I want to update the object value of `shoppingItems` 

using the es6 spread operator `updateObj` updates the Object but only inside the function

why does the Object inside `shoppingItems`  does not change its value ?

```js
const kontorGoods = [{ cheese: 5.5 }, { rice: 2.5 }, { meat: 8.8 }];
const shoppingItems = [{ cheese: 5.5 }];


function updateValue(itemIndex){
    const item = Object.values(kontorGoods[itemIndex])[0];
    updateObj(shoppingItems, itemIndex);
    console.log(updateObj(shoppingItems, itemIndex))
}


function updateObj(objArray, objIndex) {
    const currentObjkey = Object.keys(objArray[objIndex])[0];
    const currentObjValue = Object.values(objArray[objIndex])[0];
  
    return {
      ...objArray[objIndex],
      // add the key as a variable
      [currentObjkey]: currentObjValue + currentObjValue,
    };
  }

updateValue(0)
console.log(shoppingItems)
```

Comment: <pedantry>`...` isn't an operator. Operators can't do what rest and spread syntax do.</pedantry> :-)

Answer (score 0):

An object literal creates a **new** object, it doesn't have any effect at all on the things that you're using to fill in its properties, including any objects you use spread syntax on.

To update the object in the array, write back to the array:

```
    objArray[objIndex] = {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      ...objArray[objIndex],
      // add the key as a variable
      [currentObjkey]: currentObjValue + currentObjValue,
    };
```